# Select Picker plugin Bootstrap dropdown not working on mobiles/tablets

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have the select picker plugin for bootstrap (http://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/) working on my website.

Each dropdown option is a link to a different twitter page like so:

```
<select class="selectpicker" data-width="100%" name="venue" id="venue" onchange="location = this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;">
     <option value="None Selected">Choose your twitter profile</option>
     <option value="https://twitter.com/LVPLShooters">Liverpool</option>
     <option value="https://twitter.com/LeedsShooters">Leeds</option>
     <option value="https://twitter.com/MancShooters">Manchester</option>
</select>

$('.selectpicker').selectpicker();
```

It works 100% on laptops and computers. But when I use a tablet or phone the links dont work. Has anyone got any ideas on why this would be doing this?

Answer (score 0):

Replace `location = this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;` with `window.location = this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;` and try

Or use `jQuery` as below:

```
$('.selectpicker').change(function() {
    window.location = $(this).val();
});
```

**[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/manoj_admlab/4ZGrt/3/)**

Comment: Both these options didn't work :-( The first solution worked on desktops as normal. But the jquery method brought an error like this `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token .`

Comment: jsFiddle link added in answer for `jQuery` method, make sure there is not any extra `.` in your code